# Vim-airline can't be enable in windows10

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I had installed plugin vim-airline by Vundle, but it can't be enabled unless I run command `:PluginInstall` and close the window.

***update***: If I close gVim(or Vim) and open it, it doesn't work again.

I am sorry for that I can't post picture because my reputation less than 10. And you can [click here](https://gist.github.com/lucianosimon399/1a7daa6388fbf37599308a767175c6ae) to see more details on Github Gist.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If airline works after installing the plugin, what's the problem then?

Comment: If I close gVim and open it, airline doesn't work agin.